# Adobe Animate Canvas Parent Arrays?

Tags: javascript, createjs, adobe-animate

I have a game I'm making in adobe animate HTML canvas. In my code below Is there a way to combine all of the `stateItems[].stateplace1 =this.state` so I don't have like 50  different variations? I tried make the state1s the child of the StateItems but it still feels very derivative.

If stateItems and state1s were two different arrays is there a way to call the first item (Florida) of stateItems to the first target(state1)and so forth so they are "linked" so speak. Would something like that work and how would I go about do that?

I'm very new to javascript so my apologies if there is a super easy solution.

Edit: 
The StateItems are individual symbols in Animate of the actual United States of America example: Florida is a state in the literal United States so it's part of my `StateItem` array. The `stateplace` is where the states will be placed and `stateplace` is one symbol and `stateplace` 1 2 and 3 are instances of stateplace. I just wanted to know if there was a way to cleanup `the stateplace1`s in the StateItems loop so there isn't 50 `stateItems[0].stateplace1 = this.stateplace1;`
I just couldn't figure out another way to connect each StateItem to its corresponding stateplace. The code works the way I need it to I just don't know if theres a way to clean it up a bit. I hope that clears things up.

```js
var stateItems = [this.florida, this.alabama, this.southcarolina]

// we apply the same code for each symbol with the for loop
for(var i = 0; i<stateItems.length; i++){ 
 stateItems[i].on("mousedown", onMouseDown.bind(this));
 stateItems[i].on("pressmove", onMouseMove.bind(this));
 stateItems[i].on("pressup", onMouseUp.bind(this));
 stateItems[0].stateplace1 = this.stateplace1;
 stateItems[1].stateplace1 = this.stateplace2;
 stateItems[2].stateplace1 = this.stateplace3;
 stateItems[i].originX = stateItems[i].x;
 stateItems[i].originY = stateItems[i].y;
 
 
 
}

// mouse down event
function onMouseDown(evt){
 var item = evt.currentTarget;
 item.offset = {x:0, y:0};
 var pt = item.parent.globalToLocal(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);
 item.offset.x = pt.x - item.x;
 item.offset.y = pt.y - item.y;
 item.drag = true;
}
// mouse up event
function onMouseUp(evt){
 var item = evt.currentTarget;
 item.drag = false;
 var pt = item.localToLocal(item.dot.x, item.dot.y, item.state1.hitBox);
 if(item.stateplace1.hitBox.hitTest(pt.x, pt.y) ){
  item.x = item.stateplace1.x;
  item.y = item.stateplace1.y;
  item.mouseEnabled = false;   // prevents object from being move when place correctly
 }else{
  item.x = item.originX;
  item.y = item.originY;
 }
}
function onMouseMove(evt){
 var item = evt.currentTarget;
 if (item.drag){
  var pt = item.parent.globalToLocal(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);
  item.x = pt.x - item.offset.x;
  item.y = pt.y - item.offset.y;
 }
// mouse move event

}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.  What is a "state"? As far as I know, this is not an Animate/EaselJS thing.  It looks like your `stateItems` is an array pointing to 3 displayObjects. In your loop, you keep reassigning "state1" to your 3 items, but all to (as far as I can tell) undefined properties `this.state1`, `this.state2`, and `this.state3`. Maybe they are defined elsewhere? Why are different clips assigned as "state1" in each item, and why do you apply that in a loop? ----- If you describe your situation a little better, and desired behaviour, that would be ideal.

Comment: My apologies if I made it super confusing. I changed the state to stateplace in the code to make it slightly less confusing.The StateItems are individual symbols in Animate. The `stateplace` is where the statesItems will be placed and `stateplace` is one symbol and `stateplace` 1 2 and 3 are instances of stateplace. I just wanted to know if there was a way to cleanup `the stateplace1`s in the StateItems loop so there isn't 50 `stateItems[0].stateplace1 = this.stateplace1;`
I just couldn't figure out another way to connect each StateItem to its corresponding stateplace.